# Ionic framework 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' error while building apk

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build, ionic2

I am working with Ionic framework and trying to build APK, using **ionic build android** command and getting *Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'*

Here is the complete Log:

```
D:\Ionic\IonicUserBase>ionic build android
WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it.
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\Sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.


:preBuild

UP-TO-DATE

:preDebugBuild
 UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest

:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl
 UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig
 UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest
 UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac


:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

D:\Ionic\IonicUserBase\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\filetransfer\FileTransfer.java:692: error: cannot find symbol

        if (!isLocalTransfer && !Config.isUrlWhiteListed(source)) {
                                       ^
  symbol:   method isUrlWhiteListed(String)
  location: class Config
D:\Ionic\IonicUserBase\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\inappbrowser\InAppBrowser.java:122: error: cannot find symbol
                                || Config.isUrlWhiteListed(url)) {
                                         ^
  symbol:   method isUrlWhiteListed(String)
  location: class Config

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.734 secs

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
D:\Ionic\IonicUserBase\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\filetransfer\FileTransfer.java:692: error: cannot find symbol
        if (!isLocalTransfer && !Config.isUrlWhiteListed(source)) {
                                       ^
  symbol:   method isUrlWhiteListed(String)
  location: class Config
D:\Ionic\IonicUserBase\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\inappbrowser\InAppBrowser.java:122: error: cannot find symbol
                                || Config.isUrlWhiteListed(url)) {
                                         ^
  symbol:   method isUrlWhiteListed(String)
  location: class Config
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

This is my very first project with Ionic framework, and I am actually not getting the exact way to resolve this issue...

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that error is being generated by the cordova-file-transfer plugin. It's possible you have an old version as you are getting a deprecated API notice.

Try removing the plugin and re-adding it with:

`ionic plugin remove cordova-plugin-file-transfer`

Then:

`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer`

And then try rebuilding the app.